# Swap 2 numpy arrays based on condition from different arrays

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have 4 arrays, A,B,C,D.  A and B have shape (n,n) and C/D have shape (n,n,m).  I am trying to set it up so that when an element of A is greater than B, that array of length m belongs to C.  In essence
`C_new = np.where(A > B, C,D)` , `D_new = np.where(A < B , D, C)`.  However this gives me a value error (`operands could not be broadcast together with shapes`)

I am curious if  I can use `where` here instead of just looping through each element?

Edit: example:

```
A = np.ones((2,2))
B = 2*np.eye(2)
C = np.ones((2,2,3))
D = np.zeros((2,2,3))
# Cnew = np.where(A > B, C,D)-> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,2) (2,2,3) (2,2,3)
```

The Cnew would be zeros in the (0,0) and (1,1) index.

Comment: Please provide some sample data as well as the expected result. It doesn't have to be large, just a few columns and rows.

Comment: Added a simple example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a new axis at the end of the condition in order for it to broadcast correctly:

```python
C_new = np.where((A > B)[..., np.newaxis], C, D)
D_new = np.where((A < B)[..., np.newaxis], D, C)
```